# Please help me understand towing capacity

Tags: towing, trailer, trailer-hitch

I have a 2013 Nissan Rogue (front wheel drive) and I am thinking of getting a trailer hitch installed so I can transport renovation material without paying for delivery or renting a truck every time.

I read that my model of Rogue has a towing capacity of around 1,000lbs. UHaul's smallest cargo trailer at 4' x 8' weighs 850lbs empty. I also read somewhere that the towing capacity includes the weight of the vehicle, the passengers and cargo in it, as well as the trailer and any cargo it contains.

I understand that my vehicle is not a workhorse pickup truck, but how am I supposed to transport anything useful with it???

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

**Basically, you don't.** I realize that is unfortunate news, but what you've read is accurate.

Not knowing the amount of weight you'd need to be towing, one of the considerations you might want to do is to buy a small trailer which weighs much less than the U-Haul trailer and use it. You can pick up ones from Lowes or Home Depot or look online for some small trailers which would suit your needs. Get one in aluminum and it would weigh a whole lot less than what you were considering. This would give you a lot more room for cargo weight.

You're only other choice would be to get a bigger vehicle which can tow a heavier load and cover your needs.